# Turn off transactional fixtures for one spec with RSpec 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

How do I turn off transactional fixtures for only one spec (or Steak scenario) with RSpec 2?
I tried some things found on the web without any success.

This leads to an undefined method exception.

```
describe "MyClass without transactional fixtures" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  ...
end
```

This simply does nothing (transactional fixture is still on):

```
describe "MyClass without transactional fixtures" do
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  end
  ...
end
```

What else could I try?

Comment: it's really wired to want that. because you can't know what you have in your database.

Comment: I hope that's not true for your code, too ;-) But seriously, for some testing scenarios you have to disable the transactional fixtures. For example, like in my case, to test Thinking Sphinx. Sphinx needs to update the search index from the "outside". And so it has to know the database content at a specific time.

Comment: Just one thing to note;  At least in my environment ( Rails4 rspec 2 ) if you for some reason include the rspec/rails_helper in any of your rspec files, it will cause any test after it in the suite or in subsequent files to be run transactionally again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This used to be a bug (see [ticket #197](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/issue/197)), but I seems to be okay now. I just don't know if it will work on a per test base (probably not). If you want to do this, you can disable transactional fixtures globally by putting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` on the `spec_helper.rb` and use DatabaseCleaner to set that.

I've had a similar problem when testing pages with javascript on the browser (a scenario that does not work with transactional fixtures). Here's how I managed to work around it: http://github.com/lailsonbm/contact_manager_app

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the ticket, Lailson. Answer accepted :-) I also use a workaround as I don't like to disable transactional fixtures globally (too slow). I simply do a MyClass.connection.commit_db_transaction() after the objects were created. Then I do the test and afterwards delete the database entries. That works fine, and all other tests still use the transactional feature.

Comment: Nice. As I said, you can do this cleanly with DatabaseCleaner (see the github repo README I pointed to know how to do this). But your solution is viable too, just a bit error-prone. But if it's working and you're satisfied, cool… =)

Comment: I tried `MyClass.connection.commit_db_transaction` but it left the connection in an odd state where it thought it had an open transaction but it did not.  This made certain active record commands not work and also led to warnings.

This seemed to fix that problem, actually closing the transaction in the db and updating the connection to know it no longer had an open transaction:

MyClass.connection..transaction_manager.commit_transaction

Answer (score 36):

I usually add a helper like this:

```
def without_transactional_fixtures(&block)
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  yield

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end
end
```

Which lets me turn off transactional fixtures for a specific block in the specs:

```
describe "doing my thing" do
  without_transactional_fixtures do
    it "does something without transaction fixtures" do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure it works? i've tried here to test something that was using rails transactions and not worked :(

Comment: You can just change the DatabaseCleaner.strategy in a before/after block of your specs too.

Comment: Don't we have to set the ```self.use_transactional_fixtures``` to true again? in after(:all) block? I guess it will set as false for other specs which will run.

Answer (score 10):

I've did it this way, with database_cleaner, in order to test code that uses transactions (which will conflict with transactional_fixtures or any other strategy to make transactional tests e.g. DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation or :transaction):

```
# spec_helper.rb
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
config.around(:each, :testing_transactions => true) do |ex|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = nil
    ex.run
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

and in my test cases:

```
it "should not save if one of objects are invalid", :testing_transactions => true
```

Answer (score 9):

I mixed both answers and it worked for me on RSpec 3:

```
config.around(:each, use_transactional_fixtures: false) do |example|
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  example.run
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
end
```

You can then use it in the describe, context or it block

```
describe 'my test', use_transactional_fixtures: false do
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if that applies to RSpec2, but works fine with 3.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
config.around(:each, use_transactional_fixtures: false) do |example|
  self.use_transactional_tests = false
  example.run
  self.use_transactional_tests = true
end
```

Mind the `use_transactional_fixtures` (rspec-rails option) and `use_transactional_tests` (activerecord fixtures option) difference.

Answer (score 3):

Use `use_transactional_tests` instead of `use_transactional_fixtures` When Rspec 2.3.8 is being used

```
def without_transactional_fixtures(&block)
  self.use_transactional_tests = false

  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  yield

  after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  self.use_transactional_tests = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2023 answer for RSpec 6.0:

```rb
uses_transaction "doesn't run in transaction"

it "doesn't run in transaction" do
  expect(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction_open?).to eq(false)
end

it "runs in transaction" do
  expect(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction_open?).to eq(true)
end
```

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v6.0.1/spec/rspec/rails/fixture_support_spec.rb#L21

Comment: `uses_transaction` should be used with caution, as per this discussion in `rspec_rails`https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2598#issuecomment-1109445577

Answer (score 0):

I needed to switch off transactional fixtures for only one test in the suite. Nothing written above worked for me (Rails 6.1.7.6).

I had to write the test setup like that

```
describe '.method', use_transactional_fixtures: false, truncate: true do
end
```

And in the rails helper inside `Rspec.config` block, I added following code:

```
  config.before do |example|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = (example.metadata[:use_transactional_fixtures] || true)

    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = if example.metadata[:truncate]
                                 :truncation
                               else
                                 :transaction
                               end
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after do
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  end

  config.append_after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
```

This allowed me keeping transactional fixtures for all other tests in the suite

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [Maxence's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75145348/683157), I found very practical hack.

You can write this magical phrase `def self.uses_transaction?(_method) = true` in any describe/context block.

For example:

```rb
describe "transactional test" do # or context
  def self.uses_transaction?(_method) = true

  # any testcase in this block is out of transaction
end
```