# Rails 3 and Rspec 2 turn off transactional fixtures for individual tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

I am in the process of upgrading my application to Rails 3.  I started using Rspec 2 with Rails 3.  I need to turn off transactional fixtures for some of my rspec tests.  Prior I used the following code in my model specs

```
 before(:all) do
    ActiveSupport::TestCase.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  end

  after(:all) do
    ActiveSupport::TestCase.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    clean_engine_database
  end
```

**That now gives me the error:**

```
 Failure/Error: ActiveSupport::TestCase.use_transactional_fixtures = false
     undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures=' for ActiveSupport::TestCase:Class
```

Is there a way to do this per test block in Rails 3 with Rspec 2?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off transactional fixtures for one spec with RSpec 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853098/turn-off-transactional-fixtures-for-one-spec-with-rspec-2)

Comment: this doesn't seem to be duplicate. they are just related.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm looking for the answer to this question, came across [this blog entry](http://www.3hv.co.uk/blog/2009/05/08/switching-off-transactions-for-a-single-spec-when-using-rspec/)

It suggests to declare inside the describe block

```
describe "xxx" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  ...
```

I tried it with Rails 3.0.7 with RSpec 2.6.3, and looks like working.

Comment: Nice. I found that you can also put it at the beginning of a `context` block, and it will only apply to tests inside it.

Comment: Works just fine (and the same way) with rails 3.2.2 and mini-test 2.5.1

Comment: Update: Using this now gives the warning `DEPRECATION WARNING: use_transactional_fixtures= is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 5.1 (use use_transactional_tests= instead)`. However,

`self.use_transactional_tests = false` works just fine.

Comment: Oops. that's bad. Then, I have to find out workaround when I upgrade to rails 5... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable transactional fixtures globally by putting `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` on the spec_helper.rb. If you want to control them by test (e.g. use transactional just on some of them), you can set this behavior with DatabaseCleaner.

I've had a related problem when testing pages with javascript on the browser (a scenario that does not work with transactional fixtures). Here's how I managed to work around it: http://github.com/lailsonbm/contact_manager_app

Answer (score 0):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
end
```

Comment: This didn't work.  I put this in the before(:all) and it doesn't seem to work.  I'm still getting this error which is typically solved by turning off transactional fixtures for the test.

PGError: ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query

Comment: You should put this code outside any `:all` or `describe` block. The spec_helper.rb file is a good place if you wanna set this globally. And I think David meant to say `false` instead of `true`.