# Factory Girl & Rails: can we turn off the database transactions that wrap each test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, factory-bot

I've got this issue with database locking when I'm testing some threading features I've got in my application--the database locks on one thread and then all the other threads deadlock on that. As there's no explicit transaction in my code I can't just guard and release manually.

I read somewhere that fixtures in TestCase leverage implicit (implicit to MY code) transactions to clean out the database between tests, but I can't find anywhere if this is true for Factory Girl as well.

Does anyone know if it is true and if so, is there a way to turn it off for specific tests, but not all of the tests?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FactoryGirl just takes your model, sets the attributes, and calls #save on that model. I think you just need to change a setting. With RSpec, you should have a line in your spec_helper.rb file:

```
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

This config is sent to the Rails testing config. This is then used in the [#setup_fixtures](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L949) method.

The documentation on Rails [transactional fixtures](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.9/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L203)

HTH

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I wasn't sure if the configuration for this would be the same for Factory Girl...I owe you a beer.

Comment: You led me down this path to get it for individual tests...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907815/rails-3-and-rspec-2-turn-off-transactional-fixtures-for-individual-tests