# How to test Thinking Sphinx delta indexes using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, thinking-sphinx

I have used Thinking sphinx in my project and have test cases using `Rspec` for my search functionalities using setup [similar to here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277295/985051)

I have also used extensive Delta indexing in my project. How can I test my delta indexed results using rspec here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/148 (delta indexing is by default disabled in rspec test cases)

I had to set the following flags true to run the test cases:

```
ThinkingSphinx.deltas_enabled  = true
ThinkingSphinx.updates_enabled = true
```