# RSpec - How to mock a stored procedure

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rspec, mocking

Consider the following `stored procedure`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_supported_locales()
RETURNS TABLE(
  code character varying(10)
) AS
...
```

And the following method that call's it:

```
def self.supported_locales
  query = "SELECT code FROM get_supported_locales();"
  res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
  res.values.flatten
end
```

I'm trying to write a test for this method but I'm getting some problems while mocking:

```
it "should list an intersection of locales available on the app and on last fm" do
  res = mock(PG::Result)
  res.should_receive(:values).and_return(['en', 'pt'])
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.stub(:execute).and_return(res)

  Language.supported_locales.should =~ ['pt', 'en']
end
```

This test succeds but any test that runs after this one gives the following message:

```
WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
```

Why does this happen? Am I doing the mocking

The database is postgres 9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is running using database level transactions. When the test completes, the transaction is rolled back so that none of the changes made in the test are actually saved to the database. In your case, this rollback can't happen because you have stubbed out the execute method on the ActiveRecord connection.

You can disable transactions globally and switch to using [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to enable/disable transactions for various tests. You could then set up to use transactions through DatabaseCleaner by default so your existing tests don't change, and then in this one test choose to disable transactions in favor of some other strategy (such as the null strategy since there is no cleaning to be done for this test).

[This other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853098/turn-off-transactional-fixtures-for-one-spec-with-rspec-2) indicates you may be able to avoid disabling transactions globally and turn them off on a per test basis as well, I have not tried that myself though.

Comment: I ended up with unstubing the ActiveRecord ActiveRecord::Base.connection.rspec_reset